# onItemClickListener (ListActivity) vs onItemClick (ListView): which one should I use?

Tags: android, android-listview

When it comes to using the `ListView` inside of a [`ListActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html), is there a difference between applying an `OnItemClickListener` to the associated ListView and overriding the `onListItemClick` method in your ListActivity? There doesn't appear to be any difference except which class handles the event.

Is there one that is preferable to the other, whether it be for efficiency reasons, code maintainability, or Android best-practices?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Override onListItemClick if you're using listactivity. That's what it's there for.

Answer (score 1):

OnListItemClick is for ListView itself...
OnItemClickListener is for any adapter view